# How can I get the current logged in user's password in Keycloak in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, token, keycloak

I am trying to access the information of a currently logged in user in my react application from Keycloak. I have managed to get most of the information I need by the idToken like this:

```
keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(function(authenticated) {
let token = keycloak.idTokenParsed; }
```

However I am unable to access the password. Neither idToken nor the accessToken contains this information. How can I reach the password in JavaScript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `Identity Provider` (for example `Keycloak`) doesn't expose user password to service providers (react app in your case). That will be very insecure approach.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to @Jan Garajs response, I am pretty sure even Keycloak does not know the password. It is considered very insecure to store passwords in plaintext, that is why servers usually salt it, then hash it multiple (meaning thousand's of) times. The number of hashing iterations is configurable in Keycloak. This whole process is irreversible even for the server, but protects your passwords against theft.